# Using an IOService port reference to turn off a device

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit, power-management

This question relates to IO Kit programming on Mac OS X.

I have an IO Service Port reference (io_service_t).  Is there an API I can use to make whatever is on the end of that IOService port reference power off?  I have tried with all my googling might, but have not found a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Jan

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to turn that device off, then I'm sure you can send it that command, but there is no universally understood "turn off" message that's going to work on every conceivable endpoint that could potentially be on the other side of that port if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unless the device itself implements a userclient call to turn it off.  If you can modify the driver, you might be able to add such a call, but it would depend on the particular hardware you are turning off.